# AJAX call in CodeIgniter not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have an ajax call from my javascript file that is attempting to post data to a specific function in my controller.  When I view the data in the success function of my call, I get the html of a totally unrelated view as the returned data, and I am unsure why.

My AJAX call:

```
function processResults(task_id){
  var finalResults = localStorage.getItem('results');
  console.log(finalResults);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'task/getResults',
    data: {'answers': finalResults},
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
 });
}
```

My Controller function:

```
public function getResults(){

  $this->load->model('testResults');

  $finalResults = $this->input->post('answers');

  $finalResults = json_decode($finalResults, true);

  if ($taskTestId != '') {
    $this->testAnswers->insertTaskData($finalResults);
  }
}
```

Is the url in the ajax call incorrect?  I'm not really sure why it is outputting the html of a completely unrelated view.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you view the AJAX request in the network tab of developer tools what does it show?

Comment: Is the html on success one of your own views or It's for CI ? I'm suspect csrf is the problem here

Comment: @jldavis77 add **datatype:json** and try

Comment: @chris86  It shows the POST going to getResults with a 200 OK result, which I'm assuming means that it is making the correct call, but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @Mohammadhzp  Its one of my own views.

Comment: @KTAnj  I did so, but with the same results.

Comment: Can you put here the data var returned by your success function in ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last line `controller/method` passed in AJAX should be echo of something. At the end you would have something like:

```
if ($expression) {
    echo json_encode($something);
} else {
    echo json_encode($something_else);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tpojka answer will work.

But there is a more elegant way to return a JSON objet with CI

```
$this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html#CI_Output::set_content_type